# MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to string failed for value "{}" at path "userData.email" for model "order"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, rest

I want to get orders of given user search by email: "admin" and I am getting an error:

> MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to string failed for value "{}" at path "userData.email" for model "order".

And I am not getting any response.

backend - js file:

```
router.get('/user-orders', (req, res) => {
  const user = req;
  Order.find({ "userData.email": user }, (error, order) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      return res.json({ order });
    }
  })
})
```

frontend - service:

```
 userOrders(user) {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.userOrdersUrl, user);
  }
```

frontend - ts file:

```
  constructor(private orderService: OrderService, private router: Router) {
    this.orderService.userOrders('admin').subscribe(
      res => console.log(res),
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

If I declare "user" in the backend - everything works well:

```
router.get('/user-orders', (req, res) => {
  const user = 'admin';
  Order.find({ "userData.email": user }, (error, order) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      return res.json({ order });
    }
  })
})
```

[image]

But I have to send the string 'admin' from the frontend. How to fix it?

Edit:

order model:

```
const orderSchema = new Schema({
    userData: {
        firstname: String,
        lastname: String,
        address: String,
        postcode: Object,
        city: String,
        country: String,
        email: String,
        phone: Number
    },
    items: {},
    shipping: String,
    sum: Number,
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    status: {
        type:String,
        default: 'order_placed'
    }
});
```

Comment: share your model please?

Comment: ohh it seems simple: const user = req; this line is wrong, you need something like req.body.user; how do you pass user to backend?

Comment: I edited my question and add order model. I changed user to user = req.body.user; - now there is no error, but I get empty order array. There is a frontend code in my question where I am sending user ('admin') to the backend.

Comment: I dont know angular, but this:  userOrders(user) {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.userOrdersUrl, user);
  }

seems like a get request to localhost/user/someID 

if this is how you pass information to backend, then in express you extract this information like this:

req.params.someID

router.get('/user-orders', (req, res) => {}
this line look wied to me in express you would do something like
router.get('/user-orders/:userID', (req, res) => {
let user = req.params.userID
})

Comment: I don't get user id. UserOrdersUrl is a normal path - 'http://localhost:3000/api/cart/user-orders'. And "(user)" in parameter is just the string "admin". Thanks for trying to help, unfortunately, I don't understand your solution, also, it doesn't work if I don't get the user id from the path.

Comment: When I changed user = req.body.user; It almost works, only "user" sees as undefined, I do not know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your router to expect the user-id/email in the url as a path-parameter, which express will then populate under `req.params`

```
router.get('/user-orders/:id', (req, res) => {
   Order.find({ "userData.email": req.params.id}, (error, order) => { ... });
}
```

Then, in your frontend you need to adjust the url to something like:

```
userOrders(userIdOrEmail) {
   return this.http.get<User>(`${this.userOrdersUrl}/${userIdOrEmail}`);
}
```